# Is there a getCenterX() and getCenterY() method for ImageView in javaFX?

Tags: java, image, javafx, imageview, geometry

I'm using JavaFX to build a video game with different characters. Right now, they are all represented as circles, and I move them by updating their coordinates with .getCenterX() .getCenterY() and .setCenterX() .setCenterY(). However, I want to change them over to ImageView objects. Is there a similar method for ImageView? Thanks!

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/ImageView.html

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't. The Circle node is a very special case.

You should make yourself familiar with the methods [relocate](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#relocate%28double,%20double%29), [setTranslateX](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#setTranslateX%28double%29) (Y and Z) and [setLayoutX](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#setLayoutX%28double%29) (Y and Z) of the [Node](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Node.html) class. If you want to use the bounds in your calculations you can use e. g. [getBoundsInParent](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#getBoundsInParent%28%29) and [getBoundsInLocal](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#getBoundsInLocal%28%29).